# Order of pairs for each_cons(2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have a Rails 5.1 application with the following models:

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :players
end

class Player < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :games
end
```

I see the following behavior in one of `Game`s methods during tests (using standard fixtures + minitest):

```
def foo
  puts "players.first: #{players.first.id}, #{players.first.name}"
  puts "players.second: #{players.second.id}, #{players.second.name}"
  puts "players.last: #{players.last.id}, #{players.last.name}"
  players.each_cons(2) do |pair|
    puts "<<each_cons>> one: #{pair.first.id}, #{pair.first.name} - two: #{pair.second.id}, #{pair.second.name}"
  end
end
```

Output:

```
players.first: 101088061, julia
players.second: 132733334, clara
players.last: 931424614, felix
<<each_cons>> one: 931424614, felix - two: 132733334, clara
<<each_cons>> one: 132733334, clara - two: 101088061, julia
```

I would expect it to be called with `julia, clara` and then `clara, felix`. What could the reason be for this reversed order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `players.first` you are probably getting a query that selects the players with an `order by "players"."id" ASC LIMIT 1`.

When you call `second` you probably get `order by "players"."id" ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1`.

When you call `players` you do not get this ordering applied.

If this is not the behaviour you want then define:

```
@players = players.order(:id)
```

... and then `@players.first` and `@players.second` will give values consistent with the order you get from `@players` because you will be using the array implementations of `first` and `second`.

Check the logs for SQL statements to be sure.